# Adding a parameter to a public template

Tags: c++, api, templates

I have a templated API function that looks like this:

```
template<typename funcT, class T> int funcProperties(
    T      func,
    funcT  extract,
    int    limit = 0);
```

Now I want to add a flags parameter to this template. Shall I add a new template, or can I simply add the flags to the existing API, and ship it?

The new API should look like this:

```
template<typename funcT, class T> int funcProperties(
    T        func,
    funcT    extract,
    int      limit = 0,
    unsigned flags = 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on a particular case:

- you are building a library with your API and your clients link with it
- or you are shipping API as a source code and your clients compile it

In the first case, for the library to contain instantiations of your function template you probably instantiate it explicitly. If you are using `extern "C"` export then you export can only export one instantiation so it will work. If not, then each instantiation of the `funcProperties` function will have its name mangled (see [Name Mangling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling)) and each of them will contain **all template arguments**. So the exported name will change. And so, in this case your clients would have to take your new header file and recompile and link their solutions. In this case it might be more convenient for them if you add another version.

In the second case it should work - when your clients will recompile their code the template will simply be instantiated with the default value for the last template parameter.